# How to record High quality audio in android?

Tags: audio, audio-recording, camera-sound

I have tried many android application to record voice, but they're quality is not great, often it muffles the sound, as a result of forced noise removal.

But surprisingly, the video recorded from the stock camera records much much high quality sound(no distortion).
So is there is anyway to utilize this fact?

The device is a Asus Zenfone Max pro M1 (ZB601KL-4H070IN). Android Version: 8.1.0

Comment: What is the model of phone? Android version?

Comment: Asus Zenfone Max pro M1 (ZB601KL-4H070IN). Android Version: 8.1.0